# Why doesn't the vim command viB work in ruby?

Tags: vim

I would like to select the inner contents of a do/def..end block

```
def foo
    bar
end
```

e.g. bar would be selected above when hitting viB in the same way bar would be selected below in C:

```
void foo() {
    bar;
}
```

I know it probably only works for curly braces, but is there a way to make it work for do/end?

Answer (score 1):

If you tend to leave empty spaces before and after your definitions (like I do) then you can use `vip` which highlights a paragraph.